# Trying to login via php not working scripts

Tags: php, authentication, session-cookies

Hi I am trying to get the user signed in via sessions, here is my code it was working before now it isn't i didnt even change the code.

profile.php (to show after logged in)

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start(); 

$userName = $_SESSION['username'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

if(isset($_GET['session'])) {

    $currentSessionID = $_GET['session'];
    $currentSessionID = md5(md5(md5($currentSessionID)));

    session_id($currentSessionID);  

    header("Location:profile.php");
    return;

}
if(!isset($userName)){

    echo "OUT";
    return;
}

      ...
```

scripts/signin.php

```
ob_start();
session_start();
include"config.php";
echo "here";

// check for required fields
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['Username']) && isset($_POST['Password'])) {


$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);

$decrypt = md5(md5(md5($pass)));

$ensure = "select * from userinfo WHERE Username = '$user' and Password='$decrypt' and status='1'";

$result= mysql_query($ensure);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    echo "here2";   
    $entry = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());

    $_SESSION['username'] = $entry['Username'];
    echo $entry['Username'];

    $_SESSION['userid'] = $entry['Id'];

    $currentSessionID = session_id();
    $currentSessionID  = md5(md5(md5($currentSessionID)));      

    header("Location: http://www.myprocity.com/profile.php?session=".$currentSessionID);
    echo "here3";
```

the reason why im passing in the session id is because im trying to only keep sign in and sign up HTTPS while the other pages HTTP so I can show Google ads, does anyone know how to implement this without security issues (perfectly)

it always goes to OUT even when $_SESSION is my username (database is correct)

Comment: Echo out `$userName` it might be properly set/stored

Comment: What's not working? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't change `die();` to `return;`? `return` is for use within functions.

Comment: how do I set it properly? is $_SESSION['username'] = var; enough?

Comment: userName is blank string.

Comment: i was getting problem with my header line too

Comment: " it was working before now it isn't i didnt even change the code." - rubbish. If it stopped working you changed something. From what I see here this never worked.

Answer (score 0):

In `profile.php` you are checking for the presence of a session ID, and changing the session ID if you find it. You are doing this **after** you've set up a session with `session_start()`, but the PHP manual specifically says you must call `session_id()` before `session_start()` for this to work.

You're also hashing `$_GET['session']` before sending it, and again before using it. The session ID you're trying to use in `profile.php` won't match the session ID used in `signin.php`

The result is that $_SESSION does not have the data in it you are expecting.

You need to rationalise your use of `session_id()`, and ensure the correct value is passed from page to page. All the hashing with `md5()` is just complicating matters - drop it. Realistically, I don't see why you need anything more than `session_start()` at the top of each page and let PHP handle the sessions. You may have an argument for doing what you're doing, but your solution simply won't work.